# Is it a bad idea to upload my entire computer to Crashplan?

Tags: security, backup, crashplan, online-backup

**TL;DR**: From a security standpoint, is it a bad idea to upload my entire computer to Crashplan?

---

First off – despite the title of this question, I am not currently uploading my entire computer to Crashplan.

I am however uploading a lot of quite critical files from `/Library`, etc, from my OS X computer. The reason is that I want an off-site backup of large parts of my system, besides the local backup I use.

Should I be concerned, from a security-standpoint, about using Crashplan for backing up my entire computer or system-critical files?

FYI, these are some of the folders I do currently back up to Crashplan:

```
/Applications
/Library/Application Support
/Library/Developer
/Library/PreferencePanes
/Library/Preferences
/Users/me/Library/Accounts
/Users/me/Library/Application Scripts
/Users/me/Library/Application Support
/Users/me/Library/Calendars
/Users/me/Library/Containers
/Users/me/Library/CoreData
/Users/me/Library/Group Containers
/Users/me/Library/Messages
/Users/me/Library/PreferencePanes
/Users/me/Library/Preferences
/Users/me/Library/Services
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it is a security risk? Data privacy? Data theft?
Crashplan stores data in encrypted format so it is safe to a certain extent.

If you are really paranoid, just buy a local storage and backup everything there.